# Puppet exit code 6

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install **Microsoft C++ 2010 Runtime Components** for a 32 bit windows 7 machine using puppet script.

The block of code I have is --

```
package {'Microsoft2010RuntimeComponents32' :
    ensure    => 'installed',
    source    => "${src}\\vc2010_redist\\vcredist_x86.exe",
    install_options => ["/q","/log"=>"${log_5}"],
}
```

When I run puppet agent --test it is exiting with the error code 6 and I am receiving the error as

> 1;31mError: Could not set 'present' on ensure: Invalid argument - ruby_setenv at 13:/etc/puppet/modules/module_name/manifests/test.pp

Not aware of this ruby_setenv error. Can somebody pls help !!

Comment: What is on and around line 13 of the indicated manifest?

Comment: It is the end of package. A package ending curly braces.

Comment: Can you add the full declaration of that package resource to your question?